# How to remove the default "error: static assertion failed:" and print only my message in static_assert?

Tags: c++11, static-assert

Whenever assertion fails in a code like:

```
static_assert(std::get<0>(tup1) == 0, "Expected value of 0 is not there");
```

I would like my program to print only the diagnostic **Expected value of 0 is not there** instead of **error: static assertion failed: Expected value of 0 is not there**. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compiler generated error message that provides some additional context to why the code could not be compiled. It cannot be changed without changing the compiler sources (but don't do that).